# Несогласование окончания слова «день» с числительным в тултипе при наведении курсора на иконку пользователя, оставившего сообщение в основном чате

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

[image: 2 дней]

«2 дней» вместо «2 дня». С чатом «С++\С» такой проблемы не возникло, поскольку срок, прошедший со времени оставленного пользователем сообщения, не указывается вообще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уже давно исправлено:

> [image: 2 дня назад]